# How to mark a flag as required only if another flag is set in absl-py?

Tags: python, absl-py

I have two flags `f1` and `f2`, `f1` is a boolean flag. I want to mark `f2` as required whenever `f1` is set to True. Is this possible with absl-py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [validator](https://abseil.io/docs/python/guides/flags#flags-validators) for that:

```
from absl import app
from absl import flags

FLAGS = flags.FLAGS

flags.DEFINE_bool("f1", False, "some flag")
flags.DEFINE_string("f2", None, "some other flag")
flags.register_validator(
    # the flag to validate
    "f1",
    # a function that takes that flag's value and returns whether it's valid
    lambda value: not value or FLAGS.f2 is not None,
    # a message to print if it isn't
    message="if f1 is set, f2 needs to be set"
)

def main(argv):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(main)
```